# Python remove empty element by list

Tags: python-2.7, list

i have this list that contains an empty element:

```
list = ['Caramanico Terme', ' ', 'Castellafiume', ' ', 'Castelvecchio Subequo',    ' ', 'Falesia di ovindoli', ' ', 'Fara San Martino', ' ', "L'Aquila - Madonna      d'Appari", ' ', 'La Palma Pazza (Bisegna AQ)', ' ', 'Liscia Palazzo', ' ', 'Luco dei marsi', ' ', 'Montebello di Bertona', ' ', 'Monticchio', ' ', 'Palena', ' ', 'Pennadomo', ' ', 'Pennapiedimonte', ' ', 'Pescomarrino', ' ', 'Petrella', ' ', 'Pianezza', ' ', 'Pietrasecca', ' ', ' ', 'PietrePiane', ' ', 'Pizzi di Lettopalena (loc. Fonte della Noce)', ' ', 'Placche di Bini', ' ', 'Roccamorice', ' ', 'Sasso di Lucoli', ' ', 'Villetta Barrea', ' ']
```

how i can remove this '' empty element?
I have try in this way:

```
[x for x in list if all(x)]
```

but the elements are not delete
Any help?
Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at `Array.pop` 

"array.pop([i])
Removes the item with the index i from the array and returns it. The optional argument defaults to -1, so that by default the last item is removed and returned."

https://docs.python.org/2/library/array.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First of all. Make sure to not call your list `list`. That's a built-in type and will cause problems later. I renamed it to `lst`. Then you can filter the list the following way:

```
lst = ['Caramanico Terme', ' ', 'Castellafiume', ' ', 'Castelvecchio Subequo',    ' ', 'Falesia di ovindoli', ' ', 'Fara San Martino', ' ', "L'Aquila - Madonna      d'Appari", ' ', 'La Palma Pazza (Bisegna AQ)', ' ', 'Liscia Palazzo', ' ', 'Luco dei marsi', ' ', 'Montebello di Bertona', ' ', 'Monticchio', ' ', 'Palena', ' ', 'Pennadomo', ' ', 'Pennapiedimonte', ' ', 'Pescomarrino', ' ', 'Petrella', ' ', 'Pianezza', ' ', 'Pietrasecca', ' ', ' ', 'PietrePiane', ' ', 'Pizzi di Lettopalena (loc. Fonte della Noce)', ' ', 'Placche di Bini', ' ', 'Roccamorice', ' ', 'Sasso di Lucoli', ' ', 'Villetta Barrea', ' ']
filtered = [x for x in lst if len(x.strip()) > 0]
```

This will remove all kinds of whitepace elements like `' '` or `'    '` etc.

**EDIT**:

As corn3lius pointed out, this would work too:

```
filtered = [x for x in lst if x.strip()]
```

Comment: alternatively you could just do this `filtered = [x for x in lst if x.strip()]`

Answer (score 0):

You can add a condition in comprehension list:

```
l = ['Caramanico Terme', ' ', 'Castellafiume', ' ', 'Castelvecchio Subequo',    ' ', 'Falesia di ovindoli', ' ', 'Fara San Martino', ' ', "L'Aquila - Madonna      d'Appari", ' ', 'La Palma Pazza (Bisegna AQ)', ' ', 'Liscia Palazzo', ' ', 'Luco dei marsi', ' ', 'Montebello di Bertona', ' ', 'Monticchio', ' ', 'Palena', ' ', 'Pennadomo', ' ', 'Pennapiedimonte', ' ', 'Pescomarrino', ' ', 'Petrella', ' ', 'Pianezza', ' ', 'Pietrasecca', ' ', ' ', 'PietrePiane', ' ', 'Pizzi di Lettopalena (loc. Fonte della Noce)', ' ', 'Placche di Bini', ' ', 'Roccamorice', ' ', 'Sasso di Lucoli', ' ', 'Villetta Barrea', ' ']

print([l for l in list if l != ' '])
```

Answer (score 0):

Removing all items that not is ' ' i.e. the empty string is the same thing as building a set with all elements from the first set that has length > 0. This one liner takes care of that:

```
a = ['', 'apple', '', 'peach']
b = [i for i in a if i != '']
```

Answer (score 0):

Removing empty items from list. Here empty items might be in single space or multiple space within quotes. So, use `strip()` function in list comprehension.

Ex:

```py
temp_str = '      || 0X0C    ||   0X00000   ||   0X00094   ||   0X00E8C   ||           IN_OPER   ||  000000e8cff7e000 || '
temp_str.split('||')
# result: ['      ', ' 0X0C    ', '   0X00000   ', '   0X00094   ', '   0X00E8C   ', '           IN_OPER   ', '  000000e8cff7e000 ', ' ']
```

---

```
temp_list = [ x for x in temp_str.split('||') if x]
temp_list
# result: ['      ', ' 0X0C    ', '   0X00000   ', '   0X00094   ', '   0X00E8C   ', '           IN_OPER   ', '  000000e8cff7e000 ', ' ']
```

---

```
temp_list = [ x for x in temp_str.split('||') if x.strip()]
temp_list
# result: [' 0X0C    ', '   0X00000   ', '   0X00094   ', '   0X00E8C   ', '           IN_OPER   ', '  000000e8cff7e000 ']
```

---

```
temp_list = [ x.strip() for x in temp_str.split('||') if x.strip()]
temp_list
# result: ['0X0C', '0X00000', '0X00094', '0X00E8C', 'IN_OPER', '000000e8cff7e000']
```